# Return image without saving on server (node.js)

Tags: node.js, image, graphicsmagick

I create an image in GraphicsMagick on Node.js and I want to give it back without saving on server. How may I do this?

I have this code:

var fs = require('fs');
      var gm = require('gm');

```
  var captchaImg = gm.(650, 200, "#ddff99f3");

  for(var i = 0; i < 2; i ++){
      for(var j = 0; j < 5; j ++){
        ...
      }
  }

      .write("assets/images/c.jpg", function (err) {
          console.log(err);
      });
```

Write() create file on server. I can`t understand how return img without saving it in file... For example in base64.

Comment: Some code you've tried would help. We are not going to write everything for you...

Comment: Put it on the question, edit it.

Answer (score 1):

This method solved the problem:

```
captchaImg.toBuffer(function (err, buffer) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log('done!');

    console.log(buffer.toString('base64'));
});
```

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't use GraphicsMagick, but how about write to response?

```
.write(response, function (err) {
      console.log(err);
  });
```

If you use express. Maybe something like this.

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
    gm('/path/to/image.jpg')
    .resize(353, 257)
    .autoOrient()
    .write(res, function (err) {
      if (!err) console.log(' hooray! ');
    });
};
```

Comment: hmm... The code following link seems write to response, doesn't it? http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/

Comment: Yes, it is. But seems it not work with response... Or I am don`t understand nothing.